# Is There Any Reason to Put Braces for Argument-less Commands (e.g. \int{})

Tags: best-practices

Is there an reason/advantage for writing the integration (and other argumentless commands) as:
`\int{xdx}` instead of `\int xdx`? I can see the first one gives a more comprehensible code, but are there any other reasons?

Comment: `\int` is a macro without argument, so `\int{xdx}` is ... wrong, somehow. You might define a wrapper command which does typeset the differential together with the integral sign automatically

Comment: BTW, I'm asking because TeXneCenter autocompletes it as `\int{}`.

Comment: I don't have this editor to test, but after it completes, where is the cursor? If the cursor is inside the braces, for sure it has a problem. But if the cursor is after the brace, then I guess that this is a different way to allow you to type in the sequel any other letter. For example, if you press `f` after it completes, you could have an error if the result is `\intf`. But no error if the result is `\int{}f`. So, after asking to auto-complete, you don't need to worry to press `space`.

Comment: Inside the braces.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The braces are incorrect in general.

`\int` does not take an argument so the braces form a group,

`{xdx}` (or many would prefer `{x\mathrm{d}x}`) is therefore a single atom in the mathlist of type `\mathord`. In the case of `xdx` the spacing will not be affected but for example `{x+1}` differs from `x+1` in that the spacing around the `+` is frozen at its natural size, and linebreaking is suppressed. Probably you don't have integrals in inline math so this probably doesn't matter, but if the editor is routinely adding unneeded `{}` into math mode, it isn't really helping.